# Blazor WebAssembly without hosted act as client side interact with .Net Core WebAPI as server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

it is possible to let Blazor WebAssembly "without hosted" interact with .NET Core WebAPI ? For example, to do login system with JWT or CRUD.

WebAssembly without hosted - Client Side || .NET Core WebAPI - Server Side

I had done many research on internet, most of the example are either using Blazor Server App or Blazor WebAssembly "with hosted" to call a WebAPI, and its not in separate project.

Please guide me, thank you and I am new with this, please forgive me.

Comment: There is no difference where you point your `HttpClient` from your webassembly blazor, to your own API or to someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

yes possible,

first find the actual error in console .
[image]

if "cors policy error"
Then modify startup file in dotnet core web api project as below

Inside Configureservices method add Services.AddCors

```
        services.AddCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", opt => opt
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
        });
```

and in Configure method add
**app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");**

note:Add above line After app.UseHttpsRedirection(); middleware

reference:
https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-httpclient/